# Expected [START_OBJECT] under [filter]

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I want to put double filter in aggs.
such like this.

```
"aggs": {
  "download1" : {
        "filter" : [
            { "term": { "IPV4_DST_ADDR":"192.168.0.159"}},
            { "range": { "LAST_SWITCHED": { "gte": "now-5m" } }}
        ],
        "aggs" : {
            "downlod_bytes" : { "sum" : { "field" : "IN_BYTES" } }
        }
    }
}
```

but it show me an error:

```
"error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] under [filter], but got a [START_ARRAY] in [download1]",
    "line": 33,
    "col": 24
  }
]}
```

How can I do, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to combine both queries with a `bool/filter`

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "download1": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "IPV4_DST_ADDR": "192.168.0.159"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "LAST_SWITCHED": {
                  "gte": "now-5m"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "downlod_bytes": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "IN_BYTES"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it looks feasible, just the time format has some problems:"failures": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "logstash-2017.12.29",
        "node": "FnewmH4LTo6NOIyg96p2qA",
        "reason": {
          "type": "number_format_exception",
          "reason": """For input string: "now-5m""""
        }
      }
    ]

Comment: What is the data type of `LAST_SWITCHED` ?

Comment: LAST_SWITCHED is UNIX  such as 1514542090. data type: "LAST_SWITCHED":{"type":"long"}

Comment: With `long` you cannot use the date match (i.e. `now-5m`) you need to use the type `date` instead

Comment: sorry can you give me more hints : )

Comment: is it possible for you to reindex your data?

Comment: it's a little difficult because my data is updated with date such as logstash-2017.12.31  . but the answer is what I want. thx